# Intel Core i3 vs AMD A8-6600K

Tags: 64-bit, hardware, intel

I would like to buy a new computer but I dont know if the video and network cards will be compatible with Linux.

Processor: Intel Core i3
CPU Model: 3220
Processor frequency (GHz): 3.3
Standard RAM (GB): 4
HDD Capacity (GB): 500
Optical Drive: DVD-RW
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 2500

or

Processor: AMD A8-6600K
Processor frequency (GHz): 3.9
Standard RAM (GB): 6
HDD Capacity (GB): 1000
Optical Drive: DVD-RW
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon HD 8570D

If both are compatible , which one is better.

Comment: Intel's cards often have better compatibility. Could you clarify what network cards the computers have (though many work out of the box these days)?

Answer (score 1):

I have both CPU's in 2 different machines.

The A8-5600k, w/8GBRAM, 240GB SSD, and 2TB hard drive.  It runs Ubuntu 13.04, with no problems. (HD 7560D).

The i3 machine has same specs as you listed.  Also no issues with 13.04.

I would recommend the A8, for better performance, and faster processing.

We use the i3 for everyday use, and the A8 for video editing, and we're very happy with it.

Comment: But here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Identifying_Your_Graphics_Chip says that Radeon HD 8xxx series are not supported.

Comment: They are not supported with the driver included with 13.04, but you can use the driver supplied by AMD.  "The following cards require a newer version of the driver than what's found in Ubuntu 13.04/Raring's repository"  You can download the driver [here](http://www.guru3d.com/files_details/amd_catalyst_13_6_beta_download,2.html).